# Is there any way to store rowcount from above query (similar to @@rowcount) in snowflake/sql?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Im trying to count of rows from above query in a variable in snowflake sql.

Answer (score 0):

There is a global variable `SQLROWCOUNT` that stores this information.

Check out these links:

[Determining the Number of Rows Affected by DML Commands](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/dml-status.html)

[Writing Stored Procedures in Snowflake Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-snowflake-scripting.html#calling-a-stored-procedure-without-using-the-returned-value)

Sample code:

```sql
execute immediate $$
begin

  -- Insert 3 rows into a table.
  insert into my_values values (1), (2), (3);
  -- SQLROWCOUNT is not affected by statements
  -- that are not DML statements (e.g. SELECT statements).
  select * from my_values;
  -- Returns the number of rows affected by
  -- the last DML statement (the INSERT statement).
  return sqlrowcount;

end;
$$;
```